# Solr on Glassfish with Error 503

Tags: solr, glassfish-3

I'm new to Solr and I work with edited version of example-DIH from Solr examples. Everything works well using start.jar (Jetty container by Solr). But now I wanna run it on my localhost Glassfish 3.1.2.2. Solr is 4.2.1

I started here

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrGlassfish

I added properties in  Server/Properties

```
solr.data.dir with value C:/solr/example/example-DIH/solr/db/data

solr.solr.home with value  C:/solr/example/example-DIH/solr
```

I restarded server and deployed solr-4.2.1.war (found in C:\solr\dist). But when I started it, Glassfish is saying `HTTP Status 503 - Server is shutting down`

I checked the logs

> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:50.313+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.glassfish.admingui|_ThreadID=113;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|uploadFileName=solr-4.2.1.war|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:51.864+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8007:
>   Unsupported deployment descriptors element schemaLocation value
>   http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90
>   http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:51.865+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|DPL8006:
>   get/add descriptor failure : filter-dispatched-requests-enabled TO
>   false|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:52.816+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|SolrDispatchFilter.init()|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:52.864+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|No
>   /solr/home in JNDI|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:52.864+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|using
>   system property solr.solr.home: C:/solr/example/example-DIH/solr|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:52.895+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|looking
>   for solr.xml: C:\solr\example\example-DIH\solr\solr.xml|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:52.899+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|New
>   CoreContainer 1748362605|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:52.904+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Loading
>   CoreContainer using Solr Home: 'C:/solr/example/example-DIH/solr\'|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:52.905+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|new
>   SolrResourceLoader for directory:
>   'C:/solr/example/example-DIH/solr\'|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.604+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   socketTimeout to: 0|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.605+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   urlScheme to: http://|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.605+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   connTimeout to: 0|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.605+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   maxConnectionsPerHost to: 20|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.606+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   corePoolSize to: 0|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.606+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   maximumPoolSize to: 2147483647|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.607+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   maxThreadIdleTime to: 5|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.607+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   sizeOfQueue to: -1|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.608+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandlerFactory|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Setting
>   fairnessPolicy to: false|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.643+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Creating new http client, config:maxConnectionsPerHost=20&maxConnections=10000&socketTimeout=0&connTimeout=0&retry=false|#]
>
> [#|2013-04-26T13:38:53.791+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs|#]

I understand that Solr was not started but I don't know why. Did I set something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with Glassfishs key files. You can try to supply a password by adding these specific JVM parameters to the Glassfish config:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

You can do that with asadmin as well:

```
asadmin create-jvm-options -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
asadmin create-jvm-options -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

I've tried it myself but Glassfish then raises other errors related to some missing dependencies. 
Fixing these leads to other problems... :(

Comment: I'm very surpprised, this solved my problem :) Thank you very much. I'm just curious, what has keystore and truststore password to do with Solr? I was working with SSL for some time to make my own self-signed certificate to work and non of my other applications needed to set this on my server

Comment: Unbelievable. It worked. Solved my problem which was the same on a fresh glassfish 4 and a fresh glassfish 3.x installation. Like a charm!